# How to forward ref in a HOC in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using Context API to use themes in my React Native project. To consume the Theme Context, I made a Higher Order Component and passed them into the component as props.

This worked fine for the most of the app. But when I started using refs, it started crashing, because as per the documentation, the refs will not be forwarded automatically, and we need to use the `React.forwardRef` API. But something when wrong with my implementation and I am not able to resolve it.

Here's the code I have been working on:

```
// Higher order component, to wrap my component with theme (withTheme.js)
export const withTheme = (Component, areRefsUsed = false) => {
  // Logic to check if refs are being used
  if (areRefsUsed) {
    const ThemedComponent = (props, ref) => {
      return (
        <ThemeContext.Consumer>
          {theme => (<Component {...props} theme={theme} ref={ref} />)}
        </ThemeContext.Consumer>
      )
    };
    return React.forwardRef(ThemedComponent);
  }

  return (props) => {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {theme => <Component {...props} theme={theme} />}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
};

// My component where I am using refs (ExampleComponent.js)
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.refForSomeComponent = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    const { theme } = this.props;
    return (
    <Fragment>
      <Text style={{color: theme.primaryColor}}>It is working</Text>
      <TextInput ref={this.refForSomeComponent} value={'Test'} />
    </Fragment>
   )
  }
}

export default withTheme(ExampleComponent, true);
```

When I try to run the app, this error is being thrown:

```
The component for route 'ExampleComponent' must be a React component.
```

Comment: Your render method of `ExampleComponent` does not return a single element?

Comment: that was a mistake, I made while writing the sample code, but however, that is not the actual issue I'm facing.

Comment: It doesn't seem like ref issue, but maybe something with router. Are you using BrowserRouter? Can you post your configuration if you use routing in your app?